# How to visit multiple URLs within a single jmeter Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can I use different urls within a single jmeter test plan for one browser, for example:

Given an e-commerce site called www.flipcart.com

I want to visit various pages on the site such as " search result ", " Home page", "Checkout page", one by one within a single jmeter test plan.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Home Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/) **JMeter Is Not A Browser**

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

So you can use 3 different [HTTP Request Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) each having different Path and you'll be able to hit 3 pages, like:

[image: 3 different pages]

If you need to simulate different distributions, like:

- Search Results - 60% of users
- Home Page - 30% of users
- Checkout - 10% of users

You can use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller). See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for several use cases, from simplest to more complex.

Comment: Hi Dimtri,
I understand what you want to say, But can u please let me know how is the function of throughput controller OR
It is different from recording controller???

Comment: Throughput controller controls how often affected samplers are executed. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller chapter